# How to use a node api

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i have found an api for node https://github.com/schme16/node-mangafox

But i have no idea on how to use it

Lets say that i want to use this

```
mangaFox.getManga = function(callback){
    $.get('http://mangafox.me/manga/',function(data){
        var list = {};

        data.find('.manga_list li a').each(function(index, d){
            var b = $(d);           
            list[mangaFox.fixTitle(b.text())] = {id:b.attr('rel'), title:b.text()};
        });

        (callback||function(){})(list);
    }, true);
}
```

What should i do to show the list in the '/' route

This i what i have so far

```
var express     = require('express'),
    path        = require('path'),
    mangaFox    = require('node-mangafox');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

});


app.listen(1337);
console.log('oke');
```

If some cloud help me understand how this works

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    function renderList(data) {
        return Object.keys(data);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(list));
    }
    var list = mangaFox.getManga(renderList);
});
```

This is the simplest thing I can come up with. You just get the object returned by the module, list its keys, and send back that stringified as your response. Try it out. You'll probably want to replace the `renderList` with some HTML templating.